# Compress JSON using jqGrid

Tags: java, jquery, json, jboss, jqgrid

Is there a way to compress/uncompress JSON sent from an app server to a jqGrid client?

Our app server is Java/JBoss.

Comment: JSON is already pretty compact... do you mean how do I turn on gzipping?

Comment: Yes some type of zipping/compression..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like this might be the answer: (turning on gzip in JBOSS) [Cannot turn on gzip compression in JBoss 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2826059/cannot-turn-on-gzip-compression-in-jboss-5/2826698#2826698)

Comment: Thanks - suppose we'd just need to figure out how to uncompress on client for jqGrid

Comment: @Marcus: the browser will handle that automatically.

Comment: I see..  how does it know to uncompress the data?  Is there a header that indicates the data is zipped and the browser will uncompress?

Comment: @Marcus - yes, the browser sends the request into the server indicating that it can handle gzip compressed content... when the server sees this, (and you tell it to) it sends back compressed content (and includes a header that says such).  If you have Firebug installed, go to the `Net` tab and hit a few pages on StackOverflow, you'll see the headers in the request/response for each page.

Answer (score 0):

Look at [this old answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2999955/what-is-the-best-way-to-optimize-my-json-on-an-asp-net-mvc-site/3001933#3001933) where I described some ways how one can reduce the size of the transfered data using different options of the jqGrid.

If you post an example of you current JSON data sent and the current definition of `colModel` I could give you some more situation oriented advices.